# Prove $ \left|x-1\right|<1$ implies $ \left|x^2-4x+3\right|<3$.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing, absolute-value

Question:

Let $ x$ be a real number. Prove that if $ \left|x-1\right|<1$ then $ \left|x^2-4x+3\right|<3$.

---

We can write $ \left|x^2-4x+3\right|<3 $ as $ |x-3||x-1| < 3$. If I start with $ \left|x-1\right|<1$, how can I show that $ |x-3| < 3$ ?

Answer (score 4):

By the triangle inequality we obtain:
$$|x^2-4x+3|=|x-1|\cdot|x-3|\leq|x-3|\leq|x-1|+|-2|<3.$$

The triangle inequality is the following:
$$|x+y|\leq|x|+|y|$$

Answer (score 2):

Now you have $$-1 < x-1 < 1, \text{ and thus also } -3<x-3 < -1$$

So it is ensured that

$$|x^2-4x+3|=|(x-3)(x-1)| < 3$$

Comment: How did you go from $ -3<x-3 < -1$ to $ |x-3| < 3$

Comment: $−3<x−3<−1$ thus $-3 < x-3 < 3$, because $x-3 <-1<3$

Comment: So if $ x-3 < -1$ then $ x-3 < 3$ ?

Comment: Right. Could you see that? If something is smaller than -1, it is of course smaller than 3, because -1 is smaller than 3

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Per your question "how can I show that |x−3|<3 ? ", you just use the triangle inequality, and the given that $|x-1| < 1$, you got: $|x-3| = |x-1+(-2)| \le |x-1|+|-2| < 1 + 2 = 3$

Answer (score 1):

This is true for
complex numbers as well as
real numbers.

The reason is that,
if $a$, $b$, and $c$
are positive reals,
then
$b \lt c$
implies
$ab \lt ac$.
(Do you see why this is true?)

Since
$|x^2-4x+3|
= |x-1||x-3|
$,
if
$|x-1| < 1$,
then
$|x^2-4x+3|
\lt |x-3|
$.

So,
we are done
if we can show that
$|x-3| < 3$.

But,
applying the
triangle inequality
($|u+v| \le |u|+|v|$),
$|x-3|
=|x-1-2|
\le |x-1|+|-2|
\lt 1+2
=3
$.

Answer (score 1):

$|x-1|<1\implies |x^2-4x+3|=|(x-1)^2+2(1-x)|\leq $ $\leq |(x-1)^2|+|2(1-x)|<1^2+2\cdot 1=3.$